# PHP Laravel Mcrypt PHP extension required

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to PHP Laravel.

When I type like below in the command line:

```
myprofile@i3-1:/opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel-4.2.11$ php artisan generate:controller UsersController
```

I get the below error.

> Mcrypt PHP extension required.

Later I tried to troubleshoot.
Then I typed the below command.

```
myprofile@i3-1:/opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel-4.2.11$ sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

The response I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php5-mcrypt is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 662 not upgraded.
```

I again typed below:

```
myprofile@i3-1:/opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel-4.2.11$ php artisan generate:controller UsersController
```

I am unable to proceed further.
Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 1):

It should be ok!

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```